# Polymer trigger function in child element using event from parent function

Tags: javascript, html, dom, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have an element with a child element that acts as a button. When I press 'Enter' in the parent element's input box, I want to trigger the child's _runNavigation method. What is the best way to create a custom trigger where the parent fires an event to the child element?

I have tried created an EventListener in my child element:

```
<...>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" on-click="_runNavigation">{{result}}</button
<...>

Polymer({

is: 'search-button',

properties: {
    searchQuery: {
        type: String,
    }
},

ready : function (){
    document.addEventListener('fire', this._runNavigation);
},

navigate: function(url) {
    var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
    if (win != null) {
        win.focus();
    }
},


_runNavigation: function() {
    var text = this.searchQuery;
    this.navigate("https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=" + text); 
},

});
```

And firing the event when enter is pressed when the text box is in focus:

```
<...>
  <input id="input" type="text" value="{{searchQuery::input}}" on-keydown="checkForEnter" on-change="_inputChanged" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
<...>


checkForEnter: function(e) {
    // check if 'enter' was pressed
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    // enter pressed!
    console.log("ENTER!");
    this.fire('fire', {searchQuery: this.searchQuery}); 
    }
}
```

While this will fire an event that is picked up by the child element, 'this.navigate' will not run because 'this' is now the document. I have tried changing the event listener to 
    this.addEventListener('fire', this._runNavigation);
to add it to the element itself, but then the element does not detect the trigger from the parent element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you had no other choice but to use `document.addEventListener` from within your Polymer element, you'd have to set the context of `this._runNavigation` with [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
ready: function() {
  document.addEventListener('fire', this._runNavigation.bind(this)); // avoid!
}
```

While this would work in your example, it listens to the `fire` event *on the entire document*, so if any other element outside the heirarchy of your form fired that event, it would trigger your element's handler, which might be undesirable. For example:

```
  <x-form></x-form> <!-- listens to all 'fire' events -->

  <script>
    setTimeout(function() {
       // unrelated 'fire'
       document.dispatchEvent(new Event('fire'));
    }, 1000);
  </script>
```

<sup>[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/NrxQJB?editors=1001)</sup>

As you might've guessed, Polymer provides the API to fire an event on a child element...

To dispatch an event to a child, you'd set a couple options when calling [`fire()`](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/Polymer.Base#method-fire).

> `fire(type, [detail], [options])`. Fires a custom event. The `options` object can contain the following properties:
>
> - `node`. Node to fire the event on (defaults to this).
> - `bubbles`. Whether the event should bubble. Defaults to true.
> - `cancelable`. Whether the event can be canceled with preventDefault. Defaults to false.

In your case, the `bubbles` and `node` options would be useful:

```
this.fire('fire', { searchQuery: this.searchQuery }, { bubbles:false, node: this.$.searchButton });
```

Then, in your `search-button` element, you'd use:

```
this.addEventListener('fire', this._runNavigation); // bind() not necessary here
```

Note in this demo that the `fire` event does not bubble up to the document (no warning logged in event handler).

<sup>[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/xOZvNw?editors=1001)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea that fire call included the ability to include the node!

Comment: @Tykin, No problem :)